# a-tag within checkbox-label

Tags: html, css, checkbox

I've got a link inside my label which contains a for-attribute for a checkbox input-element:

```
<li>
    <label for="tab2-btn">
        <a class="menu_link" href="#the-tab-bar">Payment</a>
    </label>
</li>

[...]

<div class="tabBar" id="the-tab-bar">
   <input type="radio" name="tab" id="tab2-btn">
[...]
</div>
```

The a-Tag links to the specific dom element as expected (jumps to div with id "the-tab-bar"), but the label won't work meaning that the checkbox with the id "tab2-btn" won't be checked.

Comment: the link get the click instead of the label. Is javascript an option?

Comment: yep, it does. Unfortunately javascript shouldn't be used (ebay template)

Answer (score 0):

If you can't (or don't want to for some reason) use JavaScript/jQuery you could use the pseudo-selector `:target` instead and have the radio buttons pre-checked with the attribute `checked` (and different `name` each). This is assuming you just want one radio button to appear at a time. If this is for a form, then I wouldn't advise this route and recommend JavaScript/jQuery.

#### SNIPPET

```css
#tab1-btn:target,
#tab2-btn:target,
#tab3-btn:target {
  display: block
}
.tabBar label {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <label for="tab1-btn">
      <a class="menu_link" href="#tab1-btn">Payment 1</a>
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label for="tab2-btn">
      <a class="menu_link" href="#tab2-btn">Payment 2</a>
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label for="tab3-btn">
      <a class="menu_link" href="#tab3-btn">Payment 3</a>
    </label>
  </li>
</ul>

<div class="tabBar" id="the-tab-bar">
  <label for="tab1-btn" id="tab1-btn">
    <input type="radio" name="tab1" checked>Payment 1</label>
  <label for="tab2-btn" id="tab2-btn">
    <input type="radio" name="tab2" checked>Payment 2</label>
  <label for="tab3-btn" id="tab3-btn">
    <input type="radio" name="tab3" checked>Payment 3</label>
</div>
```